# Add elements to Nokogiri XML Builder outside of nesting

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

So I'm trying to build an XML file, and the nature of how it must be built means that I have to add elements outside of the natural nested structure. For example:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    xml.Groups do |inner|
      inner.send(:"GroupType", "test")
    end
    # Insert child element into Groups element.
  }
end
```

I want the XML to look like:

```
<Data>
  <Groups>
    <GroupType>test</GroupType>
    <AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>
  </Groups>
</Data>
```

Where `<AnotherNode>` is added **where my comment is in the first code sample**.

Should be relatively simple but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Presumably I need to be able to search for the block, or, have a reference to it when I form it and then use that?

On a side note, I've taken over a project that has a bunch of Nokogiri stuff in it already, it has selectors like:

```
xml_file = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

(xml_file/:RootNode).each do |root|
  (root/:SomeItem).each do |si|
    ...
  end
end
```

.. yet I can't find anything like that in the docs? what's it all about?

Comment: For your side note, `(xml_file/:RootNode)` is using notation originally seen in Hpricot. `/` is an alias to `search` (see http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-2F). `%`, if it were used is an alias to `at`. I don't like seeing it done that tightly because it becomes too cryptic; I'd prefer to see some whitespace around `/`.

Comment: AH. so that's valid Nokogiri syntax too? Thanks :).

Comment: Add a sample of what you expect your resulting XML to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bumped into this two years after the fact, and thought the accepted answer was way more convoluted than it needs to be.

The problem is, you're building an XML fragment here, while by default Nokogiri's builder assumes you're building a complete document.  XML documents only have one root node.

One option would be to build the complete document as follows, then grab the root's children:

```
<DISPOSABLE_OUTER_NODE>
  <Data>
    <Groups>
      <GroupType>test</GroupType>
     </Groups>
  </Data>
  <AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>
</DISPOSABLE_OUTER_NODE>
```

But there's a better, "fragmentary" way.  You build an empty fragment, then have builder work on that rather than a new document:

```
frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("")

Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with( frag ){ |b|
  b.Data do
    b.Groups do
      b.GroupType "test"
    end
  end

  b.AnotherNode "13"
}

puts frag.to_xml
```

Then just stick it into whatever document you're modifying.

Maybe `with` is a latecomer to Nokogiri.  But it's an elegant solution to a problem I was having, so I thought it belonged here.

Comment: Also worth noting, `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('')` should be equivalent to `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.new(Nokogiri::XML::Document.new)`. A little more type, but I personally think it's cleaner to not go through the parse method if you're not actually parsing XML.

Answer (score 3):

Using Nokogiri::XML::Builder only, you need to do it this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    xml.Groups {
      xml.GroupType "test"
      xml.AnotherNode "13"
    }
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
Which outputs:

=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Data>
     <Groups>
       <GroupType>test</GroupType>
       <AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>
     </Groups>
   </Data>
```

Builder is a DSL and designed as a convenience, with a limited set of capabilities. If you don't want to do it the "Builder-way" you can do it "old-school" and take an existing XML Node, and build upon it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    xml.Groups {
      xml.GroupType "test"
    }
  }
end
```

This created the base XML needed inside the Builder object. Render it as XML and reparse it into a Nokogiri::XML::Document, then work on it:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(builder.to_xml)
doc.at('GroupType').add_next_sibling("<AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>")
puts doc.to_xml

=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Data>
     <Groups>
       <GroupType>test</GroupType><AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>
     </Groups>
   </Data>

doc = Nokogiri::XML(builder.to_xml)
doc.at('Groups').add_child("<AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>")
puts doc.to_xml

=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Data>
     <Groups>
       <GroupType>test</GroupType>
     <AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode></Groups>
   </Data>
```

Either of the two above ways render the same thing syntactically, they're just cosmetically different.

You can even get convoluted and funky and do it this way:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(
  Nokogiri::XML(
    builder.to_xml
  ).at('Groups') << "<AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>"
)
puts builder.to_xml

=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Data>
     <Groups>
       <GroupType>test</GroupType>
     <AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode></Groups>
   </Data>
```

Comment: I know that, the whole idea is that I need to place the code that adds "AnotherNode" outside of the Groups builder block, as per my question.

Comment: As per your question, the output is identical to the XML you're requesting.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer my question, because my question wasn't "How do I produce the following XML?".

Comment: Then your question isn't clearly stated. You said "I want the XML to look like...", then "Where <AnotherNode> is added where my comment is in the first code sample." The XML generated in my answer is identical to what your sample is and meets your requirement.

Comment: Exactly, you didn't add <AnotherNode> where my comment is in the first code sample (outside of the Groups block).

Comment: In your sample XML, it is INSIDE the `<Groups>` block. In your code the comment says it needs to `"Insert element into Groups element above"`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're finding this quite so difficult to understand. The code that inserts the element needs to go in the position that my comment is, and the element needs to be inserted into the groups block.

Comment: Thanks for fixing up your post, that's exactly what I was after (although I was expecting it to be a bit simpler).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I guess the following code does what you want (more or less).

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    p = nil
    xml.Groups do |inner|
      inner.send(:"GroupType", "test") do |n|
        p = n.parent
      end
    end
    # Insert child element into Groups element.
    xb = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new({}, p)
    xb.someOtherChild
  }
end
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after, shame you are nearly two months too late but your solution is more adequate so you get the tick for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar, but in my case the additional XML nodes are added after the initial 'builder' object's creation. Building on the "fragmentary" answer, I discovered the Builder object has a doc attribute allowing direct access to any node in the XML via Builder.with(). The below solution would allow the 'builder' object to be passed around for functions/objects to add XML data as needed.

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Data {
    xml.Groups do |inner|
      inner.send(:"GroupType", "test")
    end  
  }
end
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(builder.doc.at('Data/Groups')) do |xml|
  xml.AnotherNode_ 13
end
```